# Is there a bug in org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm?

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, jdbcrealm

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/JDBCRealm.java.html

To use this JDBCRealm we need two tables, user and user_role.

```
user table - user_id, user_name, user_password
user_role table - user_id, role_id, user_name
```

Why user_name is required in user_role table when user_id is there as foreign key. The JDBCRealm could have used a join query to extract roles or a direct query as well if it stores the user_id from the previous query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [Tomcat 6 documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm) for `JDBCRealm`.

`user_id` is NOT required in either table, nor is `role_id`. `users` table should have `user_name` and `user_password` columns; `roles` table should have `user_name` and `role_name` columns. Tables are linked via `user_name`.

The reason it's done this way (string rather then numeric ids) is because `Principal` had name as a `String` and `isUserInRole()` call takes role name as `String` as well.

Comment: You can even use just one table for users/roles.
create table users {username varchar(64),password varchar(64),role varchar(64), UNIQUE KEY uname_key(username)); works fine.

Comment: nos that is not a normalized structure as a user can have multiple roles